# mysql - cancel source call

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I want to cancel calling a source file on a mysql server which includes an enormous amount of data. It appears to be a sqldump that is broken into many small updates for many tables.

First I tried killing the process,

```
mysql> show processlist\G
mysql> kill ###;
```

This appears to only cancel a single query inside the source file; a new process pops up and the server continues to execute the source file.

Then I tried stopping the mysql service,

```
bash> sudo service mysql stop
```

But this only paused the problem; the server threw errors constantly until I started the service again, where it picked up where it left off again.

What are my options to fully cancel this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "source file", do you mean the `source` command in the commandline tool `mysql`?  If so, you need to kill that client, not the individual commands in `PROCESSLIST`.

Go to the OS's task manager.  (You may need to be `root`.)

```
# ps -axl | grep mysql  (or other args of your picking)
# kill -9 1234567       (using the PID from the ps)
```